# Code blocks issues

Tags: c++, printf, codeblocks

Hi i'm doing a piece of coursework and im having difficulty with an error messages that i'm getting, they are:

```
error 'strtoul' was not declared in this scope
error 'print' was not declared in this scope
error 'printf' was not declared in this scope
```

the code ive entered is:

```
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

unsigned long int a, tmp;

a = strtoul("01011111000110001001001011010011",ULL,2);
print(a);

//We always work on "a" pattern
print(tmp = a >> 4);
print(tmp = a << 6);
print(tmp = a & (long int) 0x3);
print(tmp = a & (char) 0x3);
print(tmp = a | (unsigned short) 0xf00f);
print(tmp = a ^ (long int) 0xf0f0f0f0);

return 0;
}


//Function prints unsigned long integer in hexadecimal and binary notation
void print(unsigned long b)


{

    int i, no_bits = 8 * sizeof(unsigned long);
    char binary[no_bits];

    //Print hexadecimal notation
    printf("Hex: %X\n", b);

    //Set up all 32 bits with 0
    for (i = 0; i < no_bits; i++) binary[i] = 0;

    //Count and save binary value
    for (i = 0; b != 0; i++) {
        binary[i] = b % 2;
        b = b/2;
    }

    //Print binary notation
    printf("Bin: ");
    for (i = 0 ; i < no_bits; i++) {
        if ((i % 4 == 0) && (i > 0)) printf(" ");
        printf("%d", binary[(no_bits - 1) - i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

But i keep getting the error mesage:

```
error 'strtoul' was not declared in this scope
error 'print' was not declared in this scope
error 'printf' was not declared in this scope
```

no matter what i try i keep getting the same error messages when i try and declare them, any help out there??

Much appreciated,

Ben

Comment: Well, did you include required header files?

Answer (score 6):

You need to include these header files at the top of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

The [stdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/) library allows you to do input/output operations and the [stdlib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) library defines several general purpose functions, including converting a string to unsigned long integer.

You will want to move your `print` method before `main` and you should also change `ULL` to `NULL` when you call `strtoul` as I believe that was a typo. You can check out the documentation in the link I provided.

Comment: He also needs to either forward declare print or put it before main.

Comment: How do i forward declare it? I've added the two suggestions that you gave me Dan, thanks for that, but i'm still not having any joy. I'm still getting the error messages: error 'print' was not declared in this scope & error 'ULL' was not declared in this scope, to say my head is pickled is an understatement, programming doesn't come easy to me at all so i appreciate your help

Comment: @Benjamin put your print method before main, and change ULL to NULL, it was probably a typo originally. Let me know if that works for you. I will update my answer, but I am posting from my phone at the moment.

Comment: Hi Dan, no still no joy, but thanks for trying for me